# Why is it necessary to upgrade to ASA 8.4 on the way to 9.2?

Tags: cisco-asa

According to [Cisco](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/116685-problemsolution-product-00.html), if you are upgrading from Cisco ASA 8.2 to Cisco ASA 9.2 you need to perform an interim upgrade to Cisco ASA 8.4 before you continue to Cisco 9.2.

Cisco says this is because there is a change in how the ASA binaries are structured. Cisco states that if you do not perform the interim upgrade to Cisco ASA 8.4 you will receive the error message that follows.

```
No Cfg structure found in downloaded image file
```

I of course found this information *after* I upgraded a Cisco router from ASA 8.2 to 9.2 directly.

The good news is that the Cisco router still correctly migrated the configuration from 8.2 to 9.2.

My question is, does the error that Cisco cites as the reason you need to make an interim upgrade to Cisco ASA 8.4 only come up with specific configurations?

Should I factory reset the router and load my Cisco ASA 8.2 configuration? If I don't factory reset the router and load my Cisco ASA 8.2 configuration what problems (if any) should I expect given that I upgraded to Cisco ASA 9.2 without performing the interim first?

Comment: The upgrade matrix is made so that users are 100% certain to keep their configurations intact through the whole process. In your case you probably did not have any affected config and i dont think you need to fallback and redo the upgrade.

Comment: If you dig through enough docs, you'll see the reason for each interim step: specific configuration syntax changes. A direct jump may not migrate certain configs correctly/completely. The biggest change is the "New NAT" at 8.3 -- which you need to manually verify anyway.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin there is only one answer and it didn’t help. The first comment helped and I upvoted it.

Comment: You _can_ provide and accept your own answer. The idea is that we build an archive for future users to find answers.

Comment: I still don’t know the complete answer to my question so I can’t. In this case extensive testing showed that there were no problems that directly impacted this configuration.

Comment: Yes but what if I do not need it - I will convert my configuration myself. Actually I just load image from tftp and then run copy tftp: disk0:

Comment: Depending on the actual changes along the way, your old config *might* or *might not* work as expected. The update matrix is provided to ensure any necessary config changes are made during the process (syntax changes, changed defaults, ...),

Answer (score 2):

When you upgrade a device's software (firmware) you expect the configuration to be migrated so everything works just like before. For this, the new firmware has to "understand" and convert the old version's config.

Since this requires a software routine for each config version you can start the upgrade from, the range of these versions is limited.